# Add Event Listener not Connecting to Button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to click a button, that will then change the display of overlay on my page to none. In the console it is telling me that, `startButton.addEventListener` is not a function. Can someone help me find the bug?

```
const letters = document.getElementById('qwerty');
const keyWords = document.getElementById('phrase');
const startButton = document.getElementsByClassName('btn__reset');
const overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container');
var missed = 0;

startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
overlay.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the code? did you check if `startButton` is an actual element with `console.log()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your HTML. Besides that, use `startButton[0]` since `elementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection. If you want to add the listener to every button, use a loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get your button with getElementById, it works

```js
let startButton = document.getElementById('button');

startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log('yes');
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Go!</button>
```

Comment: How do you know that OP has a `<button id="button"></button>` element in their HTML?

Comment: getElementsByClassName actually returns a NodeList, this is a recomendation to the OP for a better handling of the click event.

Comment: It returns an HTMLCollection. OP may not want to or be able to change their DOM and may in fact want to attach a handler to many buttons. We need more information before it's possible to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` does not return a single element - it returns an arraylike `HTMLCollection` of all matching elements. You are not able to attach an event listener to a non-element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

If you would like to just get the first element matching a class, you can use
`const startButton = document.querySelector('.btn__reset');` (the dot signifies the selector is a class name)

Or access the first item of the return value of `getElementsByClassName` like so:
`const startButton = document.getElementsByClassName.item(0);` (You likely want to check for its existence first before)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands your 'startButton' constant is actually returning a collection from this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn__reset');
```

Even if it's a collection of only one object you need to go an additional level deeper to get the correct one

I suggest using

```
.getElementById('buttonID');
```

instead. This will will only return a single element to attach your listener to.